# How to handle '[ERR] Nodes don't agree about configuration!' in redis cluster?

Tags: redis

I started a redis cluster and found a error message '[ERR] Nodes don't agree about configuration!' and some warnings circled in red by me in the attached screenshot.
Would you please help me to analyse the root cause and advice me a solution?

The below link is related the screenshot.
Xu Liang[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoEPx.png)

Best regards,
Xu Liang

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to try is "fix": 
`redis-trib.rb fix IP:PORT`